# Can the return value of a function call be made symbolic so as to bypass executing that function?

Tags: klee

I want avoid doing inter-procedural symbolic execution. Perhaps have a return value that would not have any constraints and might resolve to any possible concrete value.

Is something like this even possible?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to avoid executing certain functions that have a very very big loop and dont really modify global data.

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality is not implemented in Klee. If you want to achieve it, you have to perform that yourself.

The file you should look at is [lib/Core/Executor.cpp](https://github.com/klee/klee/blob/master/lib/Core/Executor.cpp). Executor handles the job to execute instructions symbolically. The specific function you need to change is called "executeCall". You can check the name of the function. If that matches your target, just set the program counter to the next instruction, and make the returned value as symbolic.

With some work of programming, I think your need is achievable.

Comment: Since the return value is stored in a local/temporary register e.g. %call, and it does not have an object state or memory object associated how do I make the return value as symbolic?

Do I need to allocate more memory for the return value?

Comment: Try to look at how Klee handles the ret instruction. For memory read instructions, I know that they bind a symbolic variable to the instruction using bindLocal function.  The way they implement ret might be similar.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to manipulate the source code, you can replace those function calls with `make_symbolic` function where you basically create a fresh symbolic variable and return it as the return of the original function call. Or you could just override those functions to return a fresh symbolic value.